# I'm getting the following error when I try to run inference on an sklearn model when used as a Lambda Function on AWS

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, aws-lambda

The code used for inference is:

```
import json
import pickle
import numpy as np
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

# Function for transferring pickles from s3 to lambda 
def download_files_from_s3():
    with open('/tmp/km_model_on_space_data.pkl', 'wb') as f:
        s3.Bucket("ml-model-first-try").download_fileobj("km_model_on_space_data.pkl", f)
    with open('/tmp/tfidf_vectorizer.pkl', 'wb') as f:
        s3.Bucket("ml-model-first-try").download_fileobj("tfidf_vectorizer.pkl", f)
    with open('/tmp/cluster_distances.pkl', 'wb') as f:
        s3.Bucket("ml-model-first-try").download_fileobj("cluster_distances.pkl", f)
    with open('/tmp/space_ids_only.pkl', 'wb') as f:
        s3.Bucket("ml-model-first-try").download_fileobj("space_ids_only.pkl", f)

# Downloading files from s3 to lambda ------------ Comment the next line if data is already downloaded
download_files_from_s3()

# Loading pickles
km = pickle.load(open('/tmp/km_model_on_space_data.pkl','rb'))
tfidf_vectorizer = pickle.load(open('/tmp/tfidf_vectorizer.pkl','rb'))
cluster_distances = pickle.load(open('/tmp/cluster_distances.pkl','rb'))
space_ids = pickle.load(open('/tmp/space_ids_only.pkl','rb'))

# Automatically called everytime
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    tfidf = tfidf_vectorizer.transform([event['text']])
    cluster = km.predict(tfidf)
    cluster_arr = cluster_distances[:,cluster[0]]
    cluter_arr_sorted = cluster_arr.argsort()
    recommended_space_ids = []
    for i in cluter_arr_sorted[0:10]:
        recommended_space_ids.append(space_ids[i])
    return {'Cluster_Number' : cluster[0], 'Space_Ids' : recommended_space_ids}
```

The pickled files are stored in s3 and retrieved into lambda. Then they are used for inference. The zip file which is uploaded to s3 contains all the necessary libraries like numpy and sklearn etc along with a function.py file whose code is given above. It contains the lambda_handler which is used for inference.

The error is:

"Unable to import module 'function': dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit_multiarray)"

Comment: Please share the code that is causing the error

Comment: You need to call setup.py with Python 3 (python3 setup.py build_ext, maybe --inplace).

Comment: @amittn How am I supposed to call setup.py as I just upload the complete zip file to s3 and then provide the Object URL to my Lambda function. Also I don't understand the significance of setup.py (Why is it necessary ?). An explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: @PuranjayArora check if this link is of any help. https://github.com/cocodataset/cocoapi/issues/45

Comment: The contents of the zip file that I upload to S3 doesn't contain a 'setup.py'. The documentation of AWS lambda just says to compress all the package folders and a function.py file into a zip folder and then upload it. Then I just provide the ObjectURL of this folder (in S3) to Lambda. I don't understand how a 'setup.py' file is even involved in all this procedure ??

Comment: Any help is appreciated !!